# Ubuntu asked me to update but is not connected to the internet and hasn't been used for weeks

Tags: boot, networking, updates, malware, offline

I'm sorry if this sounds dumb. I'm new to linux and ubuntu. I like to play around with it sometimes. Just now i booted up ubuntu from an usb stick. I use a wired connection and ubuntu has airplane mode on every time it boots up. Last time i used this was 2 weeks ago.

The thing is, the cable is not yet connected and hasn't been while booting up. Somehow I got the prompt asking me to update. So i fear now that this is some kind of malware. Can someone please help me out? Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit 1:
Thank you. Here are the specs:
Ubuntu desktop 18.04.4 LTS 64-bit /
Intel i7 /
8 gb ram

Edit 2: Sorry, I should've stated my question more clearly. The two things I want to know are 1: how is this possible? and 2: can it be malware?

Edit 3: thank you all for your time. At this time I still have the PC disconnected from internet. I'm using my phone right now. What I think is that it might be malware that might have gotten in the last time I used it and presents itself as an update. Here is a screenshot but i took it with my phone. Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eei4p.jpg

Edit 4: thank you for your answer. I feel much more relaxed knowing that. Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me!

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Updates are not malware. Also, it is unclear what you want help with.

Comment: To be sure, You have permanently installed Ubuntu in an USB drive, and it is not a Live installation USB. Please clarify in the question via edit. If the prompt is a graphical window please take a screenshot of that window (Alt+PrintScreen) and upload the screenshot at imgur.com. Then edit your question and put a link of the screenshot in the question. If the prompt is in the text terminal, please copy and paste all the text from the terminal and paste it in the question above. Format the pasted commands and output as code using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: Exactly what "update" message do you get?

Comment: Doesn't airplane mode only disable wireless systems (WiFi, Bluetooth)? If you use a wired connection, what difference would airplane mode make?

Answer (score 0):

It's not malware.

Those are upgrades you had available last time you were connected. Ubuntu checks the package system for downloaded-but-not-installed upgrades at startup.

Install them.